# Como faço para coletar uma String e usar em um if?

Tags: string, ruby

```
puts "Tem dinheiro? s/n"
x = gets.chomp

if x = s
  puts "Vou viajar"
else
  puts "Não vai ser dessa vez"
end
```

Comment: Dá erro...condicionais.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `s' for main:Object (NameError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, tem que organizar o código, não é só jogar tudo de qualquer jeito.

Segundo, para comparar uma variável com um texto só é possível se este texto for expressado em sua forma literal, ou seja, deve estar entre aspas. Como se fosse uma citação em um texto.

Terceiro, no `if` está atribuindo um valor para a variável com o `=`, para comparar e obter um verdadeiro ou falso o operador correto é `==`.

Assim:

```
puts "Tem dinheiro? s/n"
x = gets.chomp
if x == "s"
    puts "Vou viajar"
else
    puts "Não vai ser dessa vez"
end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gZoh4U). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fsreigmp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/CleanString.rb).

Sugiro fazer um curso sobre programação antes de tentar escrever códigos aleatoriamente.

Comment: Obrigado =) - Eu sou novo aqui não sei como faz para imprimir o código organizado...

Comment: Eu tinha tentado dessa forma com esse mesmo raciocínio, deu o mesmo erro...estou usando o Cloud 9

Comment: Eu mostrei que funciona, e não tem muito segredo.

Comment: Sim. Eu agradeço. Um abraço

Comment: `=` é atribuição, precisa usar `==` ali

Comment: @GabrielKatakura nem tinha me atentado a isso, obrigado